# Show Entire UIPickerView and then hide UIPickerView after selected

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to create a text box that when it is selected a `UIPickerView` opens up with choices to select from. Once selected, the `UIPickerView` hides and the selected item is displayed in the text box. When I run this program the first element in the array appears but the picker does not appear. Instead, the keyboard appears. I have tried adding `CategoryPicker.delegate = self` in the `viewDidLoad()` but that line is getting error:

> a value type of UITextField has no member type delegate

This is in `swift`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add `UITextFieldDelegate`, in your ViewController, as your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` won't be called.

Secondly, make sure that your picker view is not getting covered by your textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the input for the textfield as picker view.

```
textFieldCategory.inputView = CategoryPicker
```

Comment: Now I am getting a runtime error. Thread 1: signl SIGABRT error on line 12.